# Is possible to use windows theme without they are active

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, themes

Is possible the enable/force windows theme only for my application without third party components?

Can I hook the uxTheme API to think that it is active?

Comment: Theoretically ,it is possible only if you install a global hook on uxTheme API that change the window appearance .

Comment: I don't think this makes much sense. You don't even know which theme is not active (is it luna?, zune? aero? basic? high contrast? mysavedtheme? myunsavedtheme?)

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? If the user has chosen to turn themes off your app should respect that.

Comment: Windows themes are a UI option that the user selects. Your application should not try to change the user's decisions about those sorts of things. If you think you need to do so, you need to rethink your design. :-)

Comment: I sure hope it's not possible.

Comment: I concur with Ken White - should not change the decision of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see how you could do this. Windows themes rely on DWM composition which is enabled for the login session. It cannot be partially enabled for individual applications.

Comment: Not strictly accurate - XP had themes but no DWM. I don't think the two are inexorably linked.

Comment: @Jonathan That's true. I guess I've managed to blank the memories of XP from memory. On Vista and later, I don't think you can have themed painting without composition.

Comment: @David: I'pretty sure that on Windows 7 without aero but with theme(eg the "Windows 7 Basic" theme) you dont have DWM. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Michael Yes, that is true. I rather imagine that the asker wants the full themed appearance.